# Get height of dynamically changed height div

Tags: css, html, height

How can I determine (using jQuery?) the height of a div? Its' height is not defined in CSS - so it's fluid and based on the contents.

I've tried $('#div').height() - which returns 0.

Ideas?

EDIT: (the code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PositionBottomPicture();
});

function PositionBottomPicture() {
    var parentOffset = $('#left_pane').offset();
    var parentsHeight = $('#left_pane').height();
    var childsTopPostion = (parentOffset.top + parentsHeight);


    $('#bottom_pic').offset({ top: childsTopPostion, left: parentOffset.left });
}

CSS:

#left_pane 
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 27px;
    position: relative;
}
```

where 'left_pane' and 'bottom_pic' are divs.

Thanks!

Comment: That should work. Post your HTML, CSS, and javascript. Are you executing the code in a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @roman , it should definetly giv the height of the div , where are you using this code?? is the div generated dynamically and calling code is somewhere else

Comment: @roman i am 100% confident that it will get you the height , i have used it so many times in my code , post your javascript code, we can fix the problem

Comment: @roberpitt, the issue might be  he is running the code before the dom was ready ??

Comment: It's always worth trying the same code running in the $(window).load(function(){ /* ... */}); instead of the $(document).ready(function(){ /*...*/}); just to see if it is to do with resources not being fully loaded and in place.

Comment: @david whats the difference between window load and document.ready??

Comment: @roman , if possible can you post your html also

Comment: @gov http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: @Matthew, thanks, that saved me having to find an authoritative link *and* remember the difference myself... =D

Comment: @matthew , thank you. Hi david , you are on SO...

Comment: @matthew , that site is awesome , thanks once again sharing...

Comment: @gov No problem! Welcome all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're probably not waiting for the div to load into the DOM.

Try something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var h = $("#div").height();
        var w = $("#div").width();
;})
```

Using the Document Ready tool provided by jQuery will wait till the element has been processed.

Comment: @RobertPitt What image isn't getting loaded? This can be a problem too, but there has been no mention of an image.

Comment: @gov If the `div` contained an image (and nothing else), then you could get a false reading on the height of that div, before the image loaded fully, including a `0` height or any other height inbetween 0 and the image's height (the div's height in this scenario depends on the image's height).

Comment: @Gov that code would work if `$('img')` were `$('div')` ... it's all a matter of using the right selector

Comment: @all , yeah i agree/// lets wait for his code , yeah whatever mentioned by you guys looks like right

Comment: That is exactly what i've been doing - returns 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

If 'left_pane' only contains absolutely positioned elements it's height will be zero.